# Wikipedia revision history

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, mediawiki-api

I am trying to get all revision histories for every English wikipedia article. I just need all editors' names and edition sizes (in bytes) along with the article title or id. The wikipedia dump for all revision history is a few TB and my computer cannot handle it. I also tried to use MediaWiki to query the revision histories, but it seems like it will take a very long time to get everything. Is there any other approaches I can try to get the information I want? Thanks.

Comment: Get a bigger disk / use cloud computing? There are some APIs that can technically do it, but that kind of load probably goes well beyond their intended usage.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the problem the other way around, maybe you don't need to download all the data.
For example, if you plan to use SQL, you can do it from the servers without downloading anything.

Please take a look at https://quarry.wmflabs.org/ and [its doc](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Research:Quarry).

Comment: Sorry for such late reply. Thank you very much!